# Getting system's hardware information of a connected user to a PHP website ? Is it possible?

Tags: java, php

I am posting this in order to confirm if it is possible for PHP to get a user's machine hardware information when connected to a website?

In my case I am developing an Intranet which requires one user - one machine login. Which means a user assigned to his/ her machine can only login, others cannot login from that particular machine. In this regard, my database and PHP Code is already up and running without machine dependency.

I presume it is not possible because PHP is a Server Side code which requires none of the User's system resources to get in touch with. To get system's hardware information - some application must be installed in user's machine to get it done. But is this possible in any regard for example a PHP Desktop application (though not in development) or any Java application to check machine's information and get appended it to Normal user's login.

Awaiting experts solutions...

Comment: Pretty much impossible, as you said. Javascript has a bit more access to a user's hardware,but  the extent of it is likely screen resolution and stuff.

Comment: You could place set a long lasting cookie storing which user is allowed to connect from the machine. You may encrypt it to avoid user tampering it. The question about first login on the machine arrises as well ...

Comment: Just a thought, but more of an additional question; is there anyway that the new database connection of HTML5 could help?  Such as store the user information on the machine after an intitial "IT" set-up?

Comment: @yent as you said, storing a cookie on user's machine - implies for suppose mac-id of user machine has been stored as a cookie on user's /tmp dir. But can you explain how to do it automatically ? and how can we read that cookie info from that file in PHP ? And this info must be sent to Server every time the user logins (Here username, password and mac-id all the three are checked in database). Guide me through this ...

Answer (score 1):

It depends what information you need. The HTTP Headers contain the user agent (what browers/OS) of the origin, the IP address and a few other things that the server needs in order to process the request, but you can't get for instance the brand of keyboard connected to that machine.

Comment: But for getting client side IP, "HostnameLookups" should be turned "On". 
I don't have that option in my httpd.conf .. Can you guide me ?

Comment: No, that's to get the client Hostname. The IP is obviously there, otherwise how would the server know where to send the information requested? Look up $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].

Comment: $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] and $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] return the IP-address of the server. Right ? My question is how to get the client/user side originating IP. In my case User machines are on LAN. How about now ?

Comment: Have you searched the definition of $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?

Answer (score 0):

Simple: IMPOSSIBLE! As `php` will output `text` to a browser and the browser can gather some data, but only a little (like screen resolution, colors, IP and things that are not vurnelable.). But no, PHP cannot access hardware information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IP address to know which machine it is only if your DHCP does not change the IP at each deconnexion.
You can also use the REMOTE_USER_AGENT super global to know more informations. Apart from an ajax request that can send datas that your security policy allows the browser to get, I see no solution for your problem.